# Pandas: Check if value is epoch time using python

Tags: python, date, pandas, epoch

I have a script that reads a csv like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("short.csv", parse_dates=['date'])
```

The "date" column could have any type of date formats and that works fine because I convert the date to epoch time like this:

```
df.date = pd.to_timedelta(df.date).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

A working example would be to have a csv like this:

```
date
2010-07-08 21:24:52
2010-07-08 21:24:53
```

The problem is when in the csv the date column is already in epoch time, that conversion goes really bad. So, how can I check if the column is already in epoch time before doing that conversion?

A problematic csv would be:

```
date
1433367800
1433367801
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide a couple of specific examples of cases that you have issues and cases that there are not any issues? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first omit parsing `datetime` in `read_csv` and check epoch `datetime` by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv("short.csv")

print df
         date
0  1368431150
1  1368431149
2  2015-05-18

print pd.to_numeric(df.date, errors='coerce').notnull()
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
```