# Checking a column in dataframe is in Epoch time is giving different results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, epoch, python-3.9

I wrote the below test code to check it is working properly and I get a "True" Value in the DF, but when i sure the same calculation on the just one value, it gives me "False". The correct value should be "False" as the date_time column is not in epoch/UNIX time

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
temp_list = []
i = 1
while i < 10:
    d = {
        'ticker': 'TEST',
        'date_time': datetime.now() + timedelta(days=i),
        'price': 100 + i,
        'volume': i
    }
    temp_list.append(d)
    i += 1
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=temp_list)
test_df['isepoch'] = pd.notnull(pd.to_numeric(
    test_df['date_time'], errors='coerce'))
print(test_df)
print(pd.notnull(pd.to_numeric(test_df['date_time'][0], errors='coerce')))
```

Output of the two print statements:

```
  ticker                  date_time  price  volume  isepoch
0   TEST 2021-09-16 10:33:43.285935    101       1     True
1   TEST 2021-09-17 10:33:43.285935    102       2     True
2   TEST 2021-09-18 10:33:43.285935    103       3     True
3   TEST 2021-09-19 10:33:43.285935    104       4     True
4   TEST 2021-09-20 10:33:43.285935    105       5     True
5   TEST 2021-09-21 10:33:43.285935    106       6     True
6   TEST 2021-09-22 10:33:43.285935    107       7     True
7   TEST 2021-09-23 10:33:43.285935    108       8     True
8   TEST 2021-09-24 10:33:43.285935    109       9     True
False
```

I adapted the solution from [Pandas: Check if value is epoch time using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36981213/pandas-check-if-value-is-epoch-time-using-python), to create the 'isepoch' column in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you heck [pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), `scalar`, `list`, `tuple`, `1-d array`, or `Series` can be converted as an argument for `pandas.to_numeric`.

Above your code, the part as following :

```
test_df['isepoch'] = pd.notnull(pd.to_numeric(test_df['date_time'], errors='coerce'))
```

returns **true** as `pandas.to_numeric` accepts `series` value.

However, the `test_df['date_time'][0]` is neither, `scalar`, `list`, `tuple`, `1-d array`, or `Series` as following :

```
In [1]: print(type(test_df['date_time'][0]) == list)
   ...: print(type(test_df['date_time'][0]) == tuple)
   ...: print(type(test_df['date_time'][0]) == np.array)
   ...: print(type(test_df['date_time'][0]) == pd.Series)
   ...: print(np.isscalar(test_df['date_time'][0]))
False
False
False
False
False
```

Therefore, if you change `test_df['date_time'][0]` as argument type which can be acceptable in `pandas.to_numeric`, it will return **True** value. Just like as following :

```
In [2]: pd.notnull(pd.to_numeric(np.array(test_df['date_time'][0]), errors='coerce'))
Out[2]: True
```

If you want to know more about `pandas.to_numeric` source code, you can visit [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.3/pandas/core/tools/numeric.py#L27-L242).